# 301 Redirect not working with '%'

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a 301 redirect on my WordPress site because an author's name has recently changed. Other redirects are working, but not the ones below.

```
Redirect 301 /author/old%20author /author/new_auther/
Redirect 301 /author/old%20author/ /author/new_auther/
```

Is it anything to do with the '%' characters and is there any way I can work around this without having to do it via PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for percent encoding of spaces, just enclose the URL in quotes. See also [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

> The old URL-path is a case-sensitive (%-decoded) path beginning with a slash. A relative path is not allowed.

```
Redirect "/author/old author" /author/new_auther/
```

When everything works as it should, you may change the status code to `301`. *Never* test with [`301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Comment: I did not think that would work as the URLs actually have % character in them and not spaces. Will mark correct in 10 minutes. Thanks

Comment: Good answer Olaf +1. You can also use the % sign inside double quoted uri string.

Comment: _“I did not think that would work as the URLs actually have % character in them and not spaces”_ – wrong. The URLs _do_ have spaces in them. But those spaces have been URL-encoded _as_ `%20`.